# The number of edges in a given graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For a grid graph of size $n$ in $d$ dimensions, I would like to count the number of edges connecting two vertices at distance $1$ from each other.

I thought it is $nd$ edges but it seems that I mixed it up with the number on a torus, the number on the $d-$dimensional grid should be much more!

Could you kindly help me to understand the difference and to find the number? thanks

Comment: Can you draw such graphs for small $n$ in dimensions 1 and 2?

Comment: @Aqua Yes for sure! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph#Square_grid_graph

Comment: Isn't there just *one* edge between any two adjacent vertices?

Comment: @M.Winter Yes and the goal is to count these edges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E(n,d)$ be the number of edges in the $d$-dimensional grid graph $G(n,d)$ with all sides having $n$ vertices. It should be easy to visualise the construction of $G(n,d)$ as $n$ copies of $G(n,d-1)$, and in each of the $n^{d-1}$ sets of $n$ corresponding vertices, $n-1$ edges linking them together. Thus we have
$$E(n,d)=nE(n,d-1)+(n-1)n^{d-1}$$
Couple this with the easy $E(n,1)=n-1$, and it should be easy to prove that $E(n,d)=dn^{d-1}(n-1)$.

Comment: so the number is $dn^{d}-dn^{d-1}$! Here you assumed that the graph contains $n^d$ vertices where each vertex is linked to $d$ vertices _(i.e a vertex in each direction)_ but I didn't understand why you subtract $dn^{d-1}$ ? Also, could you please clarify the difference here with the torus?

Comment: @Noah16 No, I have not assumed that. Not all vertices in my calculation have the maximum number of edges ($2d$); on a torus that would be true, and the edge count $dn^d$.